# Python - How to use .format with append to a list

Tags: python, list, format

So this might be a not smart way or maybe just a way I am thinking. I don't know but however my idea is that I am planning to use a way to add value to a list depending on a URL. Meaning that I would have two separated list where it adds if URL matches each list. I will provide an example to make it easier to understand.

```
oldListGB = []
oldListUS = []
randomwords = ['Hello', 'World']
desktop = ['GB', 'US']
while True:
    '{}{}'.format(oldList, random.choice(desktop)).append(random.choice(randomwords)
    time.sleep(2)
```

As you can se I am trying to do add either to

```
oldListGB = []
oldListUS = []
```

depending on the random and then it should add the word to whatever list it gets to. However I am not able to execute the code due to it doesn't find the word oldList.

How am I able to let it choose the correct list?

Comment: If you do not want to create any logic/list, just use `eval('{}{}'.format('oldList', random.choice(desktop))).append(random.choice(randomwords))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you the map the list's inside a dictionary.

```
lists = {
    "GB": [],
    "US": []
}

randomwords = ['Hello', 'World']
desktop = ['GB', 'US']
while True:
    selection = random.choice(desktop)
    lists[selection].append(random.choice(randomwords))
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this function since it seemed to be more clear to use with the lists with dict! Thanks! :)